# Se debería usar n-- o n-1 (JAVA)

Tags: java, array, matriz

hice un código en base a lo que me pidieron en la universidad:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código resultó así:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random r = new Random();
    int row = 4, col = 7;
    int[][] edif = new int[row][col];
    row--; col--;

    for(int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
            edif[x][y] = r.nextInt(6)+25;
            edif[x][col] += edif[x][y];
            edif[row][y] += edif[x][y];
        }
    }
    //IMPRIMIR MATRIZ Y SUMA DE CADA FILA
    System.out.println("     A      B      C      D      E      F");
    int nf = 3; //donde 3 son los números de filas, meramente estético
    for(int x = 0; x < row; x++) {
        System.out.print(""+(nf--)+" "); //se imprimirá una serie de números de acuerdo a la cantidad de filas, haciendo decremento desde 3
        for(int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
            String val = String.format("%3s",edif[x][y]);
            System.out.print(" ["+val+"] ");
        }
        String val = String.format("%3s",edif[x][col]);
        System.out.print("  {"+val+"}");
        System.out.println();
    }
    //IMPRIMIR SUMA DE CADA COLUMNA
    System.out.println();
    for(int x = 0; x < row-2; x++) {
        System.out.print("  ");
        for(int y = 0; y < col; y++) {
            String val = String.format("%3s",edif[row][y]);
            System.out.print(" {"+val+"} ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

La impresión sale como debería:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Sin embargo, tengo una duda. Está al inicio, en las declaraciones de variables. Por qué debo usar el operador de decremento en vez de solo restar 1?
- Me refiero en   row--; col--  dentro de los for;
- Si trato de usar   row-1; col-1;   Me sale un error.
- Todavía sigo aprendiendo den Java y tenía esa curiosidad.

Y, hay otras formas de realizar este mismo ejercicio? Siento que es mucho código para un ejercicio así.

Comment: `row-1` no *asigna*, en tal caso sería `row -= 1`, pero para esos casos está el operador de decremento/incremento, es más rápido de escribir y leer `--` o `++`, y todos sabemos lo que hace igualmente.

Answer (score 0):

#### Estás haciendo el array más grande de lo que es necesario.

Creas 7 columnas (de la 0 a la 6) pero solo usas las columnas de la 0 a la 5 ( `< row`, donde `row == 6`).

Lo mismo pasa con las filas.

Está bien usar el número que usas para las dimensiones en el bucle, mientras recuerdes que, como los arrays empiezan por 0, el bucle ha de ir de 0 a "tamaño - 1". Y los arrays tienen una útil propiedad `.length`.

Cambia

```
int row = 3, col = 6;
```

y elimina la línea con los decrementos.